will image lazy loading bypass windows.onload event in certain cases?
I am loading a large number of images on my webpage. My understanding is the using lazy loading allows the windows.onload event to occur sooner. If that's true, my question is this.. I am using a script section on the page which listens for the windows.onload event. If there are images which are not initially loaded due to lazy loading, will the script miss them or will the windows.onload event fire each time the user scolls and more images load? Here's the script in question...
  **<script>
    window.onload = function () {
      let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cat");

      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style = "cursor: pointer";
        elements[i].onclick = function () {
          saveProfile(elements[i]);
        };
      }
    };
  </script>**


The onload event will only be fired once. The image elements will exist in the DOM, so yes they can be selected once the page finishes loading. The lazy loading means that the browser will only fetch actual image once it's visible to the user. You won't be able to access the actual image data until the image is either programmatically or naturally loaded but, the element itself is already in the DOM.

Great answer, but it leaves one question open. Does that it mean that the script will prolong the time until the user can interact with their phone? I am concerned since there will be roughly 350 images on the page.

@Karlton Setting up event listeners for 350 images should not take any noticeable amount of time. It won't delay the page any longer than the time it takes for that script to run.
